# Django, filter and group query results by a field

Tags: python, django

I have this working but I'm sure there must be a better method

The context is a movie/television app so there are titles (movies/tv) and people who act in each, many to many relationship.

I have a "titlepeople" model with information such as:

```
id, people_fk, title_fk, role_title
```

On movies where a cast member has alot of roles I need to display their information like:
Tom Hanks: Gardener, Police Man #1, Another Role #4

Is there anyway I can optimize the below way of doing this so the code isn't so lengthy?

```
cast_unique = list()
for person in cast:
    #if not in the unique list, add them
    if person.people not in [p.people for p in cast_unique]:
        cast_unique.append(person)
    else:
        # if in the list, append the role information
        if person.role_title:
            for c in cast_unique:
                if c.people == person.people:
                    # append role info
                    c.role_title = '{0} / {1}'.format(c.role_title, person.role_title)
```

Thanks

Comment: could you paste in the `models.py` file that you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `cast_unique` to be a dictionary where you use the cast member as the key.  This will allow much greater performance because you won't have to iterate the `cast_unique` iterable.

Also, your use a list comprehension in the `if person.people not in [p.people for p in cast_unique]:` requires an entire list to be create of people for every iteration for the test; which, could use a lot of memory plus there's no way to short circuit the list comprehension when a match occurs.  Still a dictionary is a much better data type to use for this situation.

```
cast_unique = {}
for person in cast:
    if person.people not in cast_unique:
        cast_unique[person.people] = person
    else:
        cast_unique[person.people].role_title = '{0} / {1}'.format(cast_unique[person.people].role_title, person.role_title)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's obvious now you said use a dict. Time for a break!